# Dell Blade server Networking fundamentals?

Tags: networking, blade-server

i'm planing to purchase Dell m1000e blade server,
if i want to connect the server to a SAN server via Fibre Channel Blade Switch Modules should i install fiber channel host bus adapter (mezzanine card) to each server?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, of course - for each server that you plan on hooking up to the SAN. And you'll also need some form of SAN connectivity in the blade chassis. There's passthru options and built-in FC switches.

Comment: if i decided to go with iSCSI SAN storage array option for the same DELL m1000e, is there ant special networking requirements for each server or the system enclosure?

Comment: Post that as a new question. Although you may want to simply try reading the product documentation.